# Select * From a table while getting a column name as alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, alias

I would like to select all the columns in a table but one of the columns should be modified and have an alias. Is there any better way to do this rather than writing all the column names and setting alias to the required one. Like

```
SELECT
    *,
    date_format(a.date,'%m-%d-%y') AS formatDate
FROM
    myTable a
WHERE
    Id = 1;
```

Comment: Explicitly specifying column names is the right way to do it regardless of aliasing needs. `Select *` should only be used for ad-hoc throw away queries used (by a dev./support) to look at the data directly, and if you're making software to manage a database. _...and it's fine for the query in an `EXISTS` clause because the selection expressions are ignored._

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, ..., date_format(a.date, '%m-%d-%y') AS formatDate`

Comment: I want to know if there is any other way than to write all the other column names that aren't getting an alias

Comment: Just write out the column names.

Comment: @Mancity_guy no, there is no "all columns except this one" shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this work. We can select all and change the name of column(s) to alias.

Let's say we have a table **activity** with following columns where startTime stores the timestamp with date and time and we need a coulmn that just gives us the date.

```
sl.No  startTime  endTime  timeCreated
```

We can use this query

`SELECT *, date_format(startTime, '%m-%d-%Y') as startDate FROM activity` which gives us.

`sl.No  startTime  endTime  timeCreated  startDate`

This will give us an extra column compared to the original table, but we don't have to list all the columns manually to set alias for just one column.